# How to create random list without repeating one previous value?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, random

[This](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) code creates list of random numbers, but sometimes value of one previous index is repeated. I can use code below to avoid repeating, but it creates random integer, not list. So, I need to avoid list to be like this `[1,1,0,5]` and want it to be like this `[1,0,1,5]`

```
var previousIndex = 0

private fun getNewRandomIndex(): Int {
        var newIndex = -1
        while (true) {
            newIndex = random.nextInt(randomValues.size)
            if (previousIndex != newIndex) {
                previousIndex = newIndex
                break
            }
        }
        return newIndex
    }
```

I want to use created list called `randomNumbers` for this code.

```
var lastIndex = 0
 imageView.setOnClickListener {


                lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % randomNumbers.size
            button.text = randomNumbers[lastIndex].toString()
        }
```

Edited:

```
var lastIndex = 0
    val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
            while (set.size < 5) {
                set.add(getNewRandomIndex())
            }
            set.toList()

    imageView.setOnClickListener {
                    lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % set.size
                button.text = set[lastIndex].toString()
            }

    Error: No get method providing array access
```

Comment: You just don't want the same value twice? Use the code you have, remember the last value, and if it comes up next, ignore it, get the next random number until it's different from the last that was output.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I want to use list to to find a way how to solve latency problem of quiz app (see linked post) by pre-checking and pre-setting values before quiz.

Comment: One way to avoid repeats is to shuffle, rather than pick randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Set, a set is a data structure present in  languaes where it contains unique items

```
fun randomList(size: Int)List<Int> {
    val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    while (set.size < size) {
              set.add(/*your random here*/)
     }
     return set.toList()
}
```

The while makes the size is the the needed and the set makes sure thar repeated numbers on each iteration are nor added twice

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make `set` variable accessible in `onCreate()`? See my edited post. If I do like this, I get error in `set[lastIndex]`.

Comment: @vasik988 set[lastIndex] will give you error because Set belongs to Collections, so you have to iterate it...or you can convert Set to Array using `set.toArray()` which will return you array and then you can use setArray[lastIndex].

Comment: `toArray()` Gives me unresolved reference. I tried to add `import kotlin.collections` but it didn't work, how to refer to `toArray()`?

Comment: It works in the way I want when I set  `mutableListOf` instead of `mutableSetOf `. Thanks!